# Convert Ruby array of tuples into a hash given an array of keys?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an simple array

```
array = ["apple", "orange", "lemon"] 

array2 = [["apple", "good taste", "red"], ["orange", "bad taste", "orange"], ["lemon" , "no taste", "yellow"]]
```

how can i convert in to this hash whenever element in array match the first element of each element in array2?

```
hash = {"apple" => ["apple" ,"good taste", "red"],
        "orange" => ["orange", "bad taste", "orange"], 
        "lemon" => ["lemon" , "no taste", "yellow"] }
```

I am quite new to ruby, and spend a lot to do this manipulation, but no luck, any help ?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "match the first element of each element in array2"?

Comment: Don't edit my answer, leave a comment

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the order of the mapping between the key and pairs should be based on the first element in `array2`, then you don't need `array` at all:

```
array2 = [
  ["apple", "good taste", "red"],
  ["lemon" , "no taste", "yellow"],
  ["orange", "bad taste", "orange"]
]

map = Hash[ array2.map{ |a| [a.first,a] } ]
p map
#=> {
#=>   "apple"=>["apple", "good taste", "red"],
#=>   "lemon"=>["lemon", "no taste", "yellow"],
#=>   "orange"=>["orange", "bad taste", "orange"]
#=> }
```

If you want to use `array` to select a subset of elements, then you can do this:

```
# Use the map created above to find values efficiently
array = %w[orange lemon]
hash  = Hash[ array.map{ |val| [val,map[val]] if map.key?(val) }.compact ]
p hash
#=> {
#=>   "orange"=>["orange", "bad taste", "orange"],
#=>   "lemon"=>["lemon", "no taste", "yellow"]
#=> }
```

*The code `if map.key?(val)` and `compact` ensures that there is not a problem if `array` asks for keys that are not present in `array2`, and does so in `O(n)` time.*

Comment: This doesn't take into consideration the following requirement: "whenever element in array match the first element of each element in array2".

Answer (score 4):

### Paired Tuples to Hash Example

```rb
fruit_values = [
  ['apple', 10],
  ['orange', 20],
  ['lemon', 5]
]

fruit_values.to_h
# => {"apple"=>10, "orange"=>20, "lemon"=>5}
```

I decided I would leave this answer here for anyone looking to convert paired tuples into a hash.

Although it is slightly different from the question, this is where I landed on my Google search. It also matched up a bit with the original question due to the array of keys being already in the tuples. This also doesn't put the key into the value which the original question wanted, but I honestly wouldn't duplicate that data.

Answer (score 3):

This gets you the desired result.

```
hash = {}

array.each do |element|
  i = array2.index{ |x| x[0] == element }
  hash[element] = array2[i] unless i.nil?
end
```

Comment: Well that's not clear from your question. Next time reflect what you want in your example more clearly. Can `apple`, `orange` and `lemon` occur more than once in `array2`, if so how do you want the resulting hash to look. Please update your question with a clear example and expected output.

Comment: Yay, you fixed it! :) Note that while the sample data for the question was small, this answer is an `O(n*m)` algorithm for _n_ elements in `array` and _m_ elements in `array2`. If both are large, this _could_ become too slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`Array#to_h`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array:to_h) to convert directly to `Hash`:

```rb
array2 = [
  ["apple", "good taste", "red"],
  ["lemon" , "no taste", "yellow"],
  ["orange", "bad taste", "orange"]
]

map = array2.to_h { |items| [items.first, items] }
```

This would return the required:

```
{"apple"=>["apple", "good taste", "red"], "lemon"=>["lemon", "no taste", "yellow"], "orange"=>["orange", "bad taste", "orange"]}
```

Answer (score -1):

ohh..I tempted to override rassoc

Check out the following on irb

```
class Array
  def rassoc obj, place=1
    if place
      place = place.to_i rescue -1
      return if place < 0
    end

    self.each do |item|
      next unless item.respond_to? :include? 

      if place
        return item if item[place]==obj
      else
        return item if item.include? obj
      end
    end

    nil
  end
end

array = ["apple", "orange", "lemon"] 
array2 = [["apple", "good taste", "red"], ["orange", "bad taste", "orange"], ["lemon" , "no taste", "yellow"]]

Hash[ array.map{ |fruit| [fruit, array2.rassoc(fruit, nil)]}]
# this is what you want

# order changed
array2 = [["good taste", "red", "apple"], ["no taste", "lemon", "yellow"], ["orange", "bad taste", "orange"]]

Hash[ array.map{ |fruit| [fruit, array2.rassoc(fruit, nil)]}]
# same what you want after order is changed
```